# PYTHON | Как сделать переменную в JSON

Tags: python, json

У меня есть `json` в котором:

```
"perms": [
    {
        "VIP": [
            {
                "perm": [
                    "list",
                    "/list",
                    "oplist <name> lol"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Мне необходимо считать, есть ли `<name>` в json и например, при вводе oplist сделать `<name>` - любым словом/строкой/числом (не важно, главное чтобы `<name>` было любое), чтобы получилось примерно так: oplist privet lol или oplist 15 lol или oplist h lol

`Возможно ли такое реализовать?`

Comment: да, не сомневайтесь, возможно. почитайте про модуль json. Nfv dct ghjcnj

Comment: Nfv dct ghjcnj -  Там все просто